# How to modify a js function for multiple selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to modify this existing [code pen](http://codepen.io/ayazzz/pen/xqbPQj) so that instead of letting a randomizer set the width and height for a picture I want to give it a specific size (i.e. 300px by 500px).

I modified the existing code where I give an array input of pictures, which holds the pictures src and size level (1-5). 1 being the smallest and 5 being the biggest.

```
$(function() {
  var $container = $('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 200
  });
```

This is the original JS function, but as you can see itemSelector is only choosing elements with `.item` attribute. I have modified the css where I have included new attributes (.item1, .item2, .item3 ..) to match the 5 different sizes as mentioned above.

But I have tried listing the other attributes, as shown below, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
$(function() {
  var $container = $('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item, .item1, .item2, .item3, .item4, .item5',
    columnWidth: 200
  });
```

Comment: You could add another, different css class to those elements, and use *that* to select them.  This question is really all about masonry.js, and how it handles the itemSelector property.  Edit - I found a [github issue](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/77) regarding this and desandro recommended using multiple classes just as you have done, so not sure why it doesn't work since it seems to be supported.

Comment: @James you're completely correct. Thank you!